# How can I detect whether an Android device have been connected with an external keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

In my app, I have to detect whether an external keyboard is connected to the device to determine what to show to users.

I know the soft keyboard will not show if an external keyboard is connected on my device, Xoom android 3.1.

How can I know whether an Android device have been connected with an external keyboard through an USB or Bluetooth?

Thanks!

Comment: hi, you mentioned that we could use newConfig.KeyboardHidden, will you please tell me what will be displayed if the keyboard is there ? I mean the value ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a `BroadcastReceiver` and register it for an intent filter for Bluetooth actions.  You will have to search the USB API for the other.
`BroadcastReceiver`'s onReceive method will handle these activities.

Comment: Thank you. I had planed to do as you said, and I found another way to do it. Add android:configChanges="keyboard" to AndroidManifest.xml, onConfigurationChanged will be call when an external keyboard is plugging in or removing. It can be checked by [newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html#hardKeyboardHidden)

Comment: yes that nice too...you could have added this as answer and accept that,but i dont mind getting few points.

Answer (score 4):

you can find out if a bluetooth keyboard is connected to android device with
        `getResources().getConfiguration().keyboard != Configuration.KEYBOARD_NOKEYS;`

if it returns true then bluetooth keyboard is connected, false otherwise.

Comment: When i am running this code on android emulator it gives me "true" is it working no idea